# Show a knight can never tour an odd squared chess board by starting and ending at the same place

Tags: graph-theory

Show a knight can never tour an odd squared chess board by starting and ending at the same place

I can already see that solving this requires Euler's theorem and showing that since there aren't an even degree for each vertex then there can't be a Euler's cycle, but I don't know how to prove each vertex the knight only has an odd number of moves in an odd squared chess board.

Comment: By _tour_, do you mean _visit every square exactly once_?

Comment: yes sorry if that wasn't explicit

Comment: Unfortunately a knights tour has to visit all the squares (i.e. vertices) once rather than traverse all the edges, so a tour is a Hamiltonian circuit and not an Eulerian circuit. Generally Hamiltonian circuits are much harder than Eulerian circuits, but as others have already said, making use of the checkerboard colouring leads to an easy proof of impossibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An $n\times n$ chessboard has, without loss of generality, $\left\lceil\dfrac{n^2}2\right\rceil$ light squares and $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n^2}2\right\rfloor$ dark squares.  While there are equal numbers of light and dark squares if $n$ is even, there is $1$ more light square than there are dark squares if $n$ is odd.

Suppose the knight starts on a light square and makes $m$ moves.
If $m$ is even, then the knight is on the same colour square as the one on which it started.
If $m$ is odd, then the knight is on the opposite colour square.

Since the knight needs to make an even number of moves to return to its starting position, and the chessboard has an odd number of squares for odd $n$, this proves the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each knight jump is between a black and a white square. On the other hand, a tour has a fixed number of knight moves.